# Convert PHP Array to JSON Array of object

Tags: php, arrays, json, orgchart

I'm using [Google Orgchart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) in my project. In that I'm returning `JSON OBJECT` from PHP file.

**Problem**

My Problem is when I hardcode the value, It works fine. When I return data from PHP file. It did not work. I guess the data format which is returning from PHP file is not correct. File below.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        $arr1 = array(
            'v' => $row['name'],
            'f' => $row['name']+'<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>',
            '' => $row['rep'],
            '' => $row['des'],
        );
        array_push($dataarray, $arr1);
    }

echo json_encode($dataarray);
```

which returns object like below

[image]

**How it Should be**

My hardcorded `JSON OBJECT` below

```
   [
      [{v:'Prabhkar', f:'Prabhkar<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'},
       '', 'The President'],
      [{v:'Raguram', f:'Raguram<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">GM</div>'},
       'Prabhkar', 'GM']
    ]
```

Console Screenshot below:

[image]

Do I need to create a one more array in PHP file. How I suppose to change the PHP array according to above screenshot. sorry for my english. Thank you.

Comment: Show the JSON output you get `echo json_encode($dataarray);`.. Also, what's stored in `$dataarray` initially?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator, I have parsed data from `$dataarray` and shown result in screenshot `res`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap 'v' and 'f' in a array, then push other values to parent array.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        $arr1 = array(
            array(
                'v' => $row['name'],
                'f' => $row['name'] . '<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'
            ),
            $row['rep'],
            $row['des']
        );
        array_push($dataarray, $arr1);
    }

echo json_encode($dataarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your internal structure is wrong. Your internal structure is an array, with the first being a map, followed by two values. Your current implementation is an array, with only a map.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        $arr1 = array(
            array(
                'v' => $row['name'],
                'f' => $row['name'] . '<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>',
            ),
            $row['rep'],
            $row['des']);
        array_push($dataarray, $arr1);
    }

echo json_encode($dataarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your hard coded array the first key has an array inside so you must change your code like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp"); 
$dataarray = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $arr1 = array(
        array(
              'v'=> $row['name'], 
              'f' => $row['name'].'<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>',),
        $row['rep'],
        $row['des'],
    );
    array_push($dataarray, $arr1);
}

echo json_encode($dataarray);
```